# Traffic sources for a folder profile

Tags: google-analytics

I am puzzled how GA handels traffic sources for profiles that are based on a folder filter.

Example: I have a profile for a folder - www.domain.com/folder. Imagine the following scenario. A visitor comes to the homepage www.domain.com from organic search. Later the visitor navigates to www.domain.com/folder. How is this visitor shown in the traffic sources report? Is he going to be listed under organic search as this is how he landed on the website. Or as refferal or direct since he originated outside of the profile?

Comment: I'm just as puzzled as you, and that's while looking at an GA account that is actually filtered by folder - I just can't tell from the results. However there's the addIgnoredRef-method in GA, it should be enough to add this to exlude the original site as referer (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiSearchEngines#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addIgnoredRef)

Answer (score 0):

First thank you for your question (it helped me to discover and solve a problem with my own folder based setup) and second, the original source is kept (which makes sense, since everything else would break campaign reports in the folder profiles). I'm afraid though that I cannot back this up with an external reference (but I'm monitoring a large-ish site with a folder based setup and this is what I see in the results).